# Using JavaFX project to play YouTube videos and control the playback functionality

Tags: webview, youtube, javafx-8, playback, embedded-video

I already got the YouTube video embedded and working in my code. But there are certain things I would like to be able to do. Such as:

1) Make the slider bar disappear so that the user cannot skip forward in the video.

2) Know when the video is finished so that I can close the window and resume the other application.

3) The user should ideally only have one button provided by which they can start the video.

I've been searching for a few days but can't find any options to control playback of an embedded YouTube video in JavaFX. I'm not even sure if this can be done or if my approach is correct or not. Any guidance in the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code till so far.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestingJavaFX extends Application {    
public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView webview = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webview.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("https://www.youtube.com/embed/hWFDHynfl1E?autoplay=1");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(webview);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 390);

        stage.setTitle("Playing a YouTube video");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=de maybe it will help you

Comment: oh yeah. I made it work. It's pretty simple actually. Though the YouTube iframe api doesn't give you as many options as I would like. But still, it's easy enough.

Comment: @Banni How did you fix it? :)